# How to efficiently create multidimensional arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

assuming I have any function such as

f(x, y, z) = xyz

what's the fastest way of calculating every value for f given three linear input arrays x, y, and z?

Of course I can do something along the lines of,

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-1., 1., 11)
y = np.linspace(-1., 1., 11)
z = np.linspace(-1., 1., 11)

for xi, xx in enumerate(x):
    for yi, yy in enumerate(y):
        for zi, zz in enumerate(z):
            f(xi, yi, zz) = xx*yy*zz
```

but this is probably not the best way to do it, especially if the input arrays become larger. Is there a better way of doing it, such as with a list comprehension (but multidimensional) or any other way? Help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem with `x * y * z`?

Comment: Doing `x * y * z` will give me a resulting array of shape (11, ) instead of every combination of x, y, z, which will be an array of shape (11, 11, 11) for the above case.

Comment: `f(xi, yi, zz) = xx*yy*zz` doesn't work, does it?  Python doesn't allow you to assign to a function call!

Comment: How about  `x[:,None,None] * y[None,:,None]*z[None,None,:]`?  This uses `broadcasting` - it's a key concept when working with numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create the grid mesh array (x,y,z) as 3-tuples using `meshgrid` then you can apply the function in sequence:

```
import numpy as np
x = y = z = np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,11)
grid_coordinates = np.array(np.meshgrid(x,y,z)).reshape(-1,3)
f = lambda x,y,z : x*y*z
f_values = [ f(x,y,z) for x,y,z in grid_coordinates ]
```

A unit test for the `f_values`,

```
f_values[10] == grid_coordinates[10][0]*grid_coordinates[10][1]*grid_coordinates[10][2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not familiar with how meshgrids worked but this seems to be the way to do it. Going from the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) for anybody else reading this question, 'meshgrid is very useful to evaluate functions on a grid.'.

Comment: Why not just multiply the 3 arrays produced by `meshgrid`, without further reshaping and manipulating?  You are doing as much python iteration as the OP this way!

Comment: @hpaulj In this simple function, that would work but if we have nonlinear function, we would need to iterate over.

Comment: If we have to iterate, feeding scalar values to a function, there's little point to using `numpy`.  Python iteration on list is faster.

Comment: Yes we used list comprehension from plain python above
[ f(x,y,z) for x,y,z in grid_coordinates]. Sure, if function can be vectorised the better, as I said earlier.